# Need help while trying to build code in pyspark where Need to transpose multiple columns like below scenerio

Tags: python, pyspark

I have one dataset in the below format.

Sample Dataset:

[image: Sample Dataset]

Now I need to transpose(test,Opt_marks,TotalMarks) the information in the below format.

Designed output:

[image: Designed output]

I tried below but did not get the desired output.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode,create_map, lit
from functools import reduce
transpose_df= df_output.select(
    explode(
        create_map(
            *reduce(lambda y,x:x+y,
                [[lit(col), col] for col in df_output.columns]
              )
          )
      )
  )
```

Any hint or reference program will help .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added the test name to `Opt_Marks` and `TotalMarks` to make a distinction between column names:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark_playground").getOrCreate()

def test_columns_adder(df, test_name):
    df = (
        df
        .withColumn(test_name, f.when(f.array_contains(f.col('Test'), test_name), f.lit('Yes')).otherwise(f.lit('No')))
        .withColumn(f'Opt_Marks_{test_name}', f.element_at(f.col('Opt_Marks'), test_name))
        .withColumn(f'TotalMarks_{test_name}', f.element_at(f.col('TotalMarks'), test_name))
    )

    return df

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (5014970, 'IMO', 68, 100),
    (5014970, 'SMO', 14, 50),
    (5014974, 'NSO', 12, 35),
    (5014974, 'IMO', 59, 100)
], ['student_no', 'Test', 'Opt_Marks', 'TotalMarks'])

list_of_tests = [element.Test for element in df.select('Test').distinct().collect()]
df = (
    df
    .groupBy('student_no')
    .agg(
        f.collect_list(f.col('Test')).alias('Test'),
        f.map_from_arrays(f.collect_list(f.col('Test')), f.collect_list(f.col('Opt_Marks'))).alias('Opt_Marks'),
        f.map_from_arrays(f.collect_list(f.col('Test')), f.collect_list(f.col('TotalMarks'))).alias('TotalMarks')
    )
)
for test_name in list_of_tests:
    df = test_columns_adder(df, test_name)
output = df.drop('Test', 'Opt_Marks', 'TotalMarks')
output.show()
```

output:

```
+----------+---+-------------+--------------+---+-------------+--------------+---+-------------+--------------+
|student_no|IMO|Opt_Marks_IMO|TotalMarks_IMO|SMO|Opt_Marks_SMO|TotalMarks_SMO|NSO|Opt_Marks_NSO|TotalMarks_NSO|
+----------+---+-------------+--------------+---+-------------+--------------+---+-------------+--------------+
|   5014970|Yes|           68|           100|Yes|           14|            50| No|         NULL|          NULL|
|   5014974|Yes|           59|           100| No|         NULL|          NULL|Yes|           12|            35|
+----------+---+-------------+--------------+---+-------------+--------------+---+-------------+--------------+
```